# Scale an interval to $[-10,10]$

Tags: analysis

How can I scale the interval $[1,8388609]$ to the interval $[-10,10]$?

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

For any $x$ in the interval you do 
$$x' = 10\,\frac{x-4194305}{4194304}\,.$$
You can easily check that in this way $1$ is mapped in $-10$ and $8388609$ is mapped in 10. The transformation is linear and it preserves the ordering, so it is a rescaling.

Answer (score 0):

In general, one can map $[a,b]$ onto $[c,d] \forall a<b, c<d$. The idea is $[a,b] \mapsto [0,b-a] (x\mapsto x-a), [0,b-a] \mapsto [0,1] (x\mapsto \frac{x}{b-a}), [0,1] \mapsto[0, d-c] (x\mapsto (d-c)x), [0,d-c] \mapsto [c,d] (x\mapsto x+c)$

Comment: What's the reason behind the downvote?